# Running Access Macro, copying the query and pasting on Excel using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, ms-access

I have a simple process that needs automation. I run a macro on access, export the query, and then paste it on an excel file which has some graphs and tables that read from it.

For the first part of the code I now have:

```
import win32api,time
from win32com.client import Dispatch

strDbName = 'file.accdb'
objAccess = Dispatch("Access.Application")
objAccess.Visible = False
objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(strDbName)
objDB = objAccess.CurrentDb()
objAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro('Macro')
objAccess.Application.Quit() #Probably won't quit before copying values
```

I will also import xlwings, which I will use to clear the actual data and paste the new values.

The part I am having difficulties is copying the query from Access in a way I can paste in Excel via XLWings.

Thanks

Comment: if you've already got access macros why are you using python?

Comment: This is an old process that is being automated. The macro is not a block of code that a wrote, but rather a macro that joins several queries (Access - Create - Macro). The usual process is to run this macro that runs all the queries, and then extract the information to excel.

Comment: I'm thinking it would be easier to extend what you have rather than try and maintain two separate programs. For example, is there any particular reason why you have to export the queries? Can't you just have excel read what the export would be from access?

Comment: So the process could for example be like this:
Excel is connected to the Macro output through power query
Python enters access, runs macro and closes it
Python through xl wings refreshes data and pivot tables
Done

This would probably work.

We have tried to directly run the query in excel but the size of the data has made it unmanageable. Also for excel to read the macro output the macro has to be ran first, else excel gets the old values.

Comment: if access is the main app where the business logic is then, what is stopping you from  just useing access to open your excel workbook and refresh.

Comment: That would make sense. Are you talking about Access running a macro?
One more step I would like to add would be to send an email with a summary of the report, and probably that I can only do in python I believe.

Comment: yes, i forget the terminology that access uses, but you can write some VBA (rather than the drag and drop steps) that opens and refreshes your excel sheets, saves it. VBA within access also plays nicely with outlook to send emails. https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/access/open-excel-file/

Comment: Thanks for the contributions! It seems that it would be easier to write the VBA code from scratch in the next steps, asking to run the macro, open excel and refresh the query table, and then possibly send an email.
Do to being more comfortable in python I ended up running the same steps in vscode. This also has the advantage of compiling as an .exe and then anyone without any knowledge could run the .exe or schedule it. Again I did not do it in VBA because I was more comfortable with vscode and python language, but the VBA solution would possibly be much simpler. Is there a way to upvote you?